# How to redirect to an ASP app with POST data from Angular 5?

Tags: asp.net, angular, angular5

I am trying to integrate a payment gateway in my Angular app. The payment gateway is created using ASP.

The documentation given by the PG provider describes to submit a form as a POST to the given url. One the form is submitted it should redirect to the given url. Once the payment is successful PG will redirect me back to the Angular app using the redirect url I specify as one of the form data.

I have a Angular from created with necessary form fields and a button which will trigger the form submission. How does this type of submissions work in Angular? Any type of guideline or example is appreciated.

Comment: @charth, have you able to do this functionality, i'm looking exactly the same scenario but got stuck..

Comment: Yes. You have to add the `ngNoForm` directive to your form element. That way angular will skip the Angular's form handler and submit the form as a basic HTML form using the given `method` in the form.. `<form ngNoForm method="POST" action="/action.asp">...</form>`

Answer (score 0):

here is small code part i do to submit a form to an api end point. actually you do not submit the form it self, you submit an object depending on the endpoint requirements;

```
    import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';


@Injectable()
export class VehicleService {

  private readonly vehiclesEndPoint = "/api/vehicle";
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  create(vehicle: any) {

    return this.http.post(this.vehiclesEndPoint, vehicle);

  }
}
```

the response might be a json from the endpoint or a call to another endpoint that you will provide.
hope this helps

> code to happy